# How to do client side routing in Markojs

Tags: marko

how to do client side routing in Markojs. Is there anything inbuild like react router as in react?

Comment: Maybe follow this issue: https://github.com/marko-js/marko/issues/633

Comment: use - Marko Router , I discussed with marko team , They will create their own router for Marko https://www.npmjs.com/package/marko-router
or https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/marko-path-router

Answer (score 1):

Try this npm package for client side routing with marko. [marko-path-router](https://github.com/charlieduong94/marko-path-router)

Answer (score 0):

Try [marko-router5](https://github.com/jesse1983/marko-router5). It's very similar react-router or vue-router.

Answer (score -1):

I can try [marko-cli](https://github.com/marko-js/marko-cli) too and create a new project. There are a full stack to create new routes, components and tests.